# Correct usage of 'proverbial'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, expressions

Is it the correct usage of the word '**proverbial**' to suggest to someone who is completely bald that they need to '*let their proverbial hair down*'?

Comment: I don't think so. Proverbial usually means a saying that is said often, like "proverbial monkeys typing on typewriters."

Comment: Are there no example sentences in dictionaries, Simon?

Comment: I disagree with Michael Wang. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the correct usage.

> proverbial
>   adjective
>   used in a proverb or other phrase:
>
> The players pointed the proverbial finger at themselves as the ones
>   needing to improve.

[Proverbial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proverbial)

```
Examples:
```

> A place where you can let your proverbial hair down and party like an
>   animal, the Ice House has something for everyone
>
> So this is when you let your proverbial hair down a little and can
>   really be yourself.
>
> you have to let your proverbial hair down a bit and show your human
>   side to your audience
>
> People like to get a glimpse at the real people behind a brand so
>   don't be afraid to let your proverbial hair down once in a while and
>   share

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to provide a helpful answer rather than a snarky comment. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/let-your-hair-down) tells us that **let your hair down** means:

> to allow yourself to behave much more freely than usual and enjoy yourself

It's quite a well-known *phrase*, originating from around the 17th century:

> Letting one's hair down was a commonplace part of womens' daily activities in the 17th century. The hair was normally pinned up and was let down for brushing or washing.

So - hair up for being sensible, and hair down away from civilised company.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/proverbial) says that **proverbial** means:

> *(of a word or phrase)* referred to in a proverb or idiom.
>
> *The title of the movie refers to the proverbial elephant in the living room*

This construction is used to indicate figurative speech where it could be ambiguous; there is not *literally* an elephant in the room.

---

Back to your phrase - the person is not necessarily bald, and most probably no hair will be touched, they are referring to the figurative expression meaning to behave freely.